# How to "blend" two values without overflow?

Tags: c, algorithm, integer-overflow

Consider the following function:

```
// Return a blended value of x and y:
//   blend(100, 200, 1, 1) -> 150
//   blend(100, 200, 2, 1) -> 133
uint8_t blend(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, uint8_t parts_x, uint8_t parts_y) {
  uint32_t big_parts_x = parts_x;
  uint32_t big_parts_y = parts_y;
  return (uint8_t) ((big_parts_x * x + big_parts_y * y) /
                    (big_parts_x + big_parts_y));
}
```

Is there a way to get *close* to appropriate return values without requiring any allocations greater than `uint8_t`? You could break it up (less rounding) into an addition of two `uint16_t` easily by performing two divisions. Can you do it with only `uint8_t`?

Comment: All the operands will be promoted to `int` before the math is done, and if `int` is at least 4 bytes, your calculation won't overflow that, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have operations on 8 bits for my target architecture, hence the question. I should have phrased it as "without requiring any operations on types other than uint8_t".

Comment: "have operations on 8 bits for my target architecture" does not limit C code to only 8-bit integer math.  Classic example: First PCs used 8-bit processors, lack 16 bit or wider math ops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standards compliant C implementation is guaranteed to perform arithmetic operations with at least 16 bits.

Section 6.3.1.1p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) states:

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or `unsigned
>   int` may be used:
>
> - An object  or  expression  with  an  integer  type  (other  than `int` or `unsigned int` ) whose  integer  conversion  rank  is  less  than
>     or  equal  to  the  rank  of `int` and `unsigned int` .
> - A bit-field of type
>     `_Bool` , `int` , `signed int` ,or `unsigned int` .
>
> If  an `int` can  represent  all  values  of  the  original  type  (as 
>   restricted  by  the  width,  for  a bit-field),  the  value  is 
>   converted  to  an `int` ; otherwise,  it  is  converted  to  an `unsigned
>   int` . These  are  called  the *integer promotions*. All  other 
>   types  are  unchanged  by  the integer promotions.

Section E.1 also states that an `int` **must** be able to support values at least in the range -32767 to 32767, and an `unsigned int` **must** support values in at least the range 0 to 65535.

Since a `uint8_t` has lower rank than an `int`, the former will always be promoted to the latter when it is the subject of most operators, including `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`.

Given that, you can safely compute the value with the following slight modification:

```
uint8_t blend(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, uint8_t parts_x, uint8_t parts_y) {
    return ((1u*parts_x*x) / (parts_x + parts_y)) + ((1u*parts_y*y) / (parts_x + parts_y));
}
```

The expressions `parts_x*x` and `parts_y*y` will have a maximum value of 65025.  This is too big for a 16 bit `int` but not a 16 bit `unsigned int`, so each is multiplied by `1u` to force the values to be converted to `unsigned int` as per the **usual arithmetic conversions** specified in section 6.3.1.8:

> the  integer  promotions  are  performed  on  both  operands.   Then  the
>   following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>
> - If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
> - Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned integer  types,  the  operand  with  the  type  of  lesser 
>     integer  conversion  rank  is converted to the type of the operand
>     with greater rank.
> - **Otherwise,  if  the  operand  that  has  unsigned  integer  type  has  rank  greater  or equal  to  the  rank  of  the  type  of  the 
>     other  operand,  then  the  operand  with signed  integer  type  is 
>     converted  to  the  type  of  the  operand  with  unsigned integer
>     type.**

Note also that we divide each part by the sum total separately.  If we added both parts first before dividing, the numerator could exceed 65535.  By doing the division first, this brings each subexpession back down into the range of a `uint8_t`.  Then we can add the two parts which will again be in the range of a `uint8_t`.

So the above expression is guaranteed to return a correct exact answer on a compiler that is compliant with the C standard.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get close to appropriate return values without requiring any allocations greater than uint8_t?

In theory, yes:

```
uint8_t blend(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, uint8_t parts_x, uint8_t parts_y) {
  return lookup_table[x][y][parts_x][parts_y];
}
```

In practice that's going to cost 4 GiB of RAM for the lookup table, so it's probably not a great idea.

Apart from that, it depends on what you mean by "close" (how large "acceptable worst case error" can be) and what range of values are valid (especially for `parts_x` and `parts_y`).

For example (if `parts_x` and `parts_y` have a range from 1 to 15 only):

```
uint8_t blend(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, uint8_t parts_x, uint8_t parts_y) {
  uint8_t scaleX = (parts_x << 4) / (parts_x + parts_y);
  uint8_t scaleY = (parts_y << 4) / (parts_x + parts_y);

  return (x >> 4) * scaleX + (y >> 4) * scaleY;
}
```

Of course in this case "close" means:

- blend(100, 200, 1, 1) = 6*8 + 12*8 = 144 (not 150)
- blend(100, 200, 2, 1) = 6*10 + 12*5 = 120 (not 133)

Note that (in general) multiplication is "expanding". What I mean is that if `a` has M bits of range and `b` has N bits of range, then `a*b` will have M+N bits of range. In other words (using full range) to avoid overflow `uint8_t * uint8_t = uint16_t`. Division is significantly worse (e.g. to avoid precision loss, 1/3 needs infinite bits), some precision loss is impossible to avoid, the number of bits in the result determines how much precision loss, and 8 bits of precision is "not much".

Also note that the simple example I've shown above can be improved for some cases by adding extra code for those cases. For example:

```
uint8_t blend(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, uint8_t parts_x, uint8_t parts_y) {
  if(parts_x < parts_y) {
     return blend(y, x, parts_y, parts_x);
  }
  // parts_x <= parts_y now

  if(parts_x == parts_y*2) {
      return 2*(x/3) + y/3;
  } else if(parts_x == parts_y*3) {
      return 3*(x/4) + y/4;
  } else if(parts_x == parts_y*4) {
      return 4*(x/5) + y/5;
  } else if(parts_x == parts_y*5) {
      return 5*(x/6) + y/6;
  } else if( (x > 16) && (y > 16) ){
      uint8_t scaleX = (parts_x << 4) / (parts_x + parts_y);
      uint8_t scaleY = (parts_y << 4) / (parts_x + parts_y);

      return (x * scaleX + y * scaleY) >> 4;
  } else {
      uint8_t scaleX = (parts_x << 4) / (parts_x + parts_y);
      uint8_t scaleY = (parts_y << 4) / (parts_x + parts_y);

      return (x >> 4) * scaleX + (y >> 4) * scaleY;
  }
}
```

Of course it's significantly easier and faster to use something larger than `uint8_t`, so...

Comment: `(parts_x << 4) / (parts_x + parts_y)` still uses at least 16 bit math as part of the addition.  The compiler does not know `parts_x, parts_y` is of range 1...15 and will add `parts_x + parts_y` as it they were `int` (16, 32 bit math).  The same for the shift and division.  Code could use something like `(uint8_t)(parts_x << 4) / (uint8_t)(parts_x + parts_y)`  to inform the compiler that the intermediate terms are 8-bit and then the compiler may emit 8-bit code.

Comment: @chux: Yes, you're right (compiler would need to analyse all callers to determine the real range of the input args).

Answer (score 1):

The below will combine without any additional allocations.
Works even if `int/unsigned` is 16 bit.

```
return (uint8_t) ((1u*parts_x*x + 1u*parts_y*y) / (0u + parts_x + parts_y));
```

Comment: @Brendan Code does not use `int`, but `unsigned`.  OP specifically was referring to "requiring any allocations".  There are no such intermediate objects here.  Any math operation will promote operands to `unsigned/int` as down here to `unsigned`.  So unless OP does not want to use any operands, `+,-,*,/,%,&,^,|, ||,&&, []`, etc. than conversion to `unsigned/int` must be part of the answer.

Comment: Semantics. Your code uses an `unsigned int` which is most definitely larger than 8 bits. I would assume (for the question to make sense at all) that the code is being compiled for some kind of 8-bit microcontroller that has no support for anything except 8 bit integers.

Comment: @Brendan Not semantics.  C _specifies_ adding (subtracting, adding, ...) of 2 `uint8_t` as in `x+ y` to occur using at least 16-bit math (as part of the _usually integer promotions_).  In C, code _cannot_ perform `x+y` using only 8-bit math - the sum is at least 16-bit.  The native bit width of a processor is irrelevant C has been hosted on many an 8-bit processor.  Even a Turing machine (1-bit processor) can do C addition which is at least 16-bits wide.

Comment: C specifies that all code behaves "as if" the rules were followed. What this means is that when 2 `uint8_t` variables are added the generated code can ignore the rules and do an 8 bit addition (that happens to behave "as if" the variables were promoted).

Comment: @chux Can you provide a reference to addition of uint8_t using at least 16-bit math? I don't doubt you, but I'm unfamiliar with where to look for that.

Comment: @ToBeReplaced C11 6.3.1.8 "Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to determine a **common real type** for the operands and result." One or both operands go through _usual arithmetic conversions_  which causes _integer promotions_ on narrow types like `uint8_t` to `int/unsigned`.   The _minimum_ range of `int/unsigned` is -32767...32767, 0, 65535. (16-bit) §5.2.4.2.1

Comment: @chux: In that case your answer should be "`No, in C it's impossible to do it with uint8_t only because C "will" (may, depending on what the optimiser felt like doing) promote intermediate results to a larger size`"; and your answer (and the accepted answer) is still wrong because it says it's possible.

Comment: @Brendan OP's restrictions are "without requiring any allocations greater than uint8_t" and "do it with only uint8_t".  The accepted answer and this one do not employ additional allocations of objects of even 8-bit size.

Comment: @Brendan Ehhhhh either way the discussion is helpful to me. My main takeaway is "if I have a C compiler, I get access to a bare-minimum of 16-bit unsigned math, which is enough to perform the calculation accurately", and that holds even if I'm on an 8-bit processor. I think your answer is still valuable though, as if you change my question to have x/y/parts_x/parts_y be uint16_t instead, your answer explains what would have to happen to get to a solution.

Comment: @ToBeReplaced With a C99 compiler , code has access to at least 64-bit integer math using `long long`. The underlying bit width of the processor obviously results in certain emitted code efficiencies but not the integer   range of the language.  Integer ranges are influenced by the processor, but the C has certain minimums - even for a 1 bit processor.  For `int` that is at least 16-bit.  For `long long`, that is at least 64-bit.  TLDR: The processor bit width is not important to this question.